# How can i access the array objects and call them again with new created function? Using the example of problematic codes

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me what problems these JavaScript programs involve?
I would be very grateful for your advice and suggestions as well as correction!

There is an array. Three functions should be created from this array.
Write the following three functions. All three should use the volcanoes
array to determine what to return.

GetVolcanoByName - this function expects a string as an argument
and returns the object in the volcanoes array whose name property is equal
to the string that is passed to it (if there is one).

getVolcanoesByCountry - this function expects a string as an argument and
returns an array containing the objects in the volcanoes array whose
country properties are equal to the string that is passed to it.

getAverageHeight - this function returns the average height of all the
volcanoes in the array.

```js
 let volcanoes = [
    createVolcano('Eyjafjallajökull', 'Iceland', 1651),
    createVolcano('Krakatoa', 'Indonesia', 2850),
    createVolcano('Manua Loa', 'USA', 4169),
    createVolcano('Mount Etna', 'Italy', 3326),
    createVolcano('Mount Fuji', 'Japan', 3778),
    createVolcano('Mount Saint Helens', 'USA', 2549),
    createVolcano('Mount Vesuvius', 'Italy', 1281)
];



function getVolcanoByName() {
        for (var i = 0; i < volcanoes.length; i++) {
            let volcano = volcanoes[i];
            if (volcano.name === name) {
                return name;
            }
        }
    }

function getVolcanoesByCountry(country) {
        return this.volcanoes.filter((volcano) => {
            return volcano.country
        });

    }


 function getAverageHeight(heightInMeters) {
     var sum = 0;
     for(var i = 0; i < volcanoes.heightInMeters.length; i++) {
         sum += volcanoes.heightInMeters[i]; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: First problem is `createVolcano` is never defined.

Comment: Your question is that you need help with creating correct functions for this problem ?

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. Can you may me explain what is the best way to fix the problem?

Comment: It would actually be a lot better if you could tell us what the problem is. This is the same as telling your car mechanic that the car is making a noise, which can be so many things. There should be errors when running the code. Those errors show up in the developer console of your browser. With those errors you get information on what went wrong. Look the error up with a search engine. It is likely that someone else experienced the same problem and found a solution. If you'll run the snippet above, you'll see your first error.

Comment: What did you try (is the above code actually the result of an own attempt)? Where got you stuck? How about providing the implementation of the factory function `createVolcano` to the audience( / question) as well?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources about functions ...

- [JavaScript > Reference > Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)
- [JavaScript > Guide > Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)
- [JavaScript reference > Standard built-in objects > Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Let us implement the missing factory `createVolcano`, a functions which assembles/builds/creates and returns an object ...

```
function createVolcano(name, country, currentHeight) {
  return {
    name,
    country,
    heightInMeters: currentHeight,
  };
}
```

Let's continue with reading about [*Destructuring assignment(s)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) especially about how to [unpack fields from objects passed as a function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter).

Within a next step we implement `getVolcanoByName` which will be based upon [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)ing an item within an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instance by a certain condition ...

```
function getVolcanoByName(list, value) {
  return list.find(({ name }) => name === value);
}
```

Then we're moving towards the implementation of `getVolcanoesByCountry` which will be based upon [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)ing one or more items from a given array (again by a condition), returning a new array with just the filtered item(s) ...

```
function getVolcanoesByCountry(list, value) {
  return list.filter(({ country }) => country === value);
}
```

Finally we are left with the calculation of `getAverageVolcanoeHeight`, where we will use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in order to sum-up the total height of all of a list's volcanoe items. The result (total height) then immediately is divided by the amount of volcanoe items involved of the calculation ...

```
function getAverageVolcanoeHeight(list) {
  return (list.reduce((total, { heightInMeters }) =>

    (total + heightInMeters), 0

  ) / list.length);
}
```

Together with the OP's example one can run and test the above implemented / provided code ...

```js
function getVolcanoByName(list, value) {
  return list.find(({ name }) => name === value);
}
function getVolcanoesByCountry(list, value) {
  return list.filter(({ country }) => country === value);
}
function getAverageVolcanoeHeight(list) {
  return (list.reduce((total, { heightInMeters }) =>

    (total + heightInMeters), 0

  ) / list.length);
}

function createVolcano(name, country, currentHeight) {
  return {
    name,
    country,
    heightInMeters: currentHeight,
  };
}

const volcanoeList = [
  createVolcano('Eyjafjallajökull', 'Iceland', 1651),
  createVolcano('Krakatoa', 'Indonesia', 2850),
  createVolcano('Manua Loa', 'USA', 4169),
  createVolcano('Mount Etna', 'Italy', 3326),
  createVolcano('Mount Fuji', 'Japan', 3778),
  createVolcano('Mount Saint Helens', 'USA', 2549),
  createVolcano('Mount Vesuvius', 'Italy', 1281),
];
console.log({ volcanoeList });

console.log(
  'getVolcanoByName(volcanoeList, "Mount Saint Helens") ...',
  getVolcanoByName(volcanoeList, "Mount Saint Helens")
);
console.log(
  'getVolcanoByName(volcanoeList) ...',
  getVolcanoByName(volcanoeList)
);

console.log(
  'getVolcanoesByCountry(volcanoeList, "Italy") ...',
  getVolcanoesByCountry(volcanoeList, "Italy")
);
console.log(
  'getVolcanoesByCountry(volcanoeList) ...',
  getVolcanoesByCountry(volcanoeList)
);

console.log(
  'getAverageVolcanoeHeight(volcanoeList) ...',
  getAverageVolcanoeHeight(volcanoeList)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Very good and detailed explanation! Thank you for the friendly suggestions with understandable tips!

Comment: @ Peter Seliger: He is a very good programer with a good didactic competence in the field. His answer was really helpful, also to understanding.